# Warning: Unused parameter 'self' AwesomeProject/...React.xcodeproj/RCTProfile.m

Tags: react-native

Trying out react native iOS

Update: This is only when building and running one on a device!

I get the following warnings in RCTProfile.m:

```
static IMP RCTProfileMsgForward(NSObject *self, SEL selector)
```

Unused parameter 'self'
Unused parameter 'selector'